# pickle can't serialize ftplib.FTP_TLS instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, pickle, dill

My codes is like below, just need to pickle.dumps a ftp instance, but got a `TypeError: an integer is required` error.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pickle
from ftplib import FTP_TLS


class FtpClient(object):
    """
    Create sftp instance;then implemnet all sftp methods
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.ftps = FTP_TLS()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ftps = FtpClient()
    pickle_ftps = pickle.dumps(ftps)
    print("pickle_ftps:", pickle_ftps)
```

Traceback could see as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/PythonCodes/pythonlearning/python_learning_ftp_pickle_issue.py", line 19, in <module>
    pickle_ftps = pickle.dumps(ftps)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1380, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 669, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 731, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 669, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 71, in _reduce_ex
    state = base(self)
TypeError: an integer is required
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Could anyone offer some suggestions? I've searched answers in the internet, it seems `dill` module can solve this problem, but this module couldn't be used in my system, Could anyone know the root cause?

Comment: As the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) states, you can pickle "instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section [Pickling Class Instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) for details)". In a nuthsell, you could add special methods like `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` to your class that determine what information about the class instance is saved and how it restored when unpickled.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have tried __getstate__ and __setstate__ but all in vain, from this sentences "instances of such classes whose __dict__ or the result of calling __getstate__() is picklable (see section Pickling Class Instances for details)." perhaps FTP_TLS instance(sftp based on tcp socket) is not picklable, that's the root cause.

Comment: Yes, that's causing the issue, but you can work around it by defining your own `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods. The first would need to save enough `FTP_TLS` instance information for the latter to restore the "state" of the instance when it's unpickled — with _you_ deciding what that means. As an example of solving a similar problem: You can't pickle a `file` object, so if you had one as an attribute of one of your own classes, you could save its filename and current position when pickling instance of your class and then use that to later restore that part of the class.